# extendscript after effects colorize not working or how do i add it

Tags: extendscript

am trying to add the effect Colorize Blue wash  or Colorize -blue wash to my seleced layer it does not work.
when manually selected it adds color balance and color balance hld with modified setting .

now how do i use my code

```
var myComp = app.project.activeItem;
var preCompLayer = myComp.selectedLayers[0];
preCompLayer.property("Effects").addProperty("Colorize - blue wash");
```

image below snapshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to apply a preset as though are you applying an effect. First you'll need to find the path to the preset file in your After Effects installation. You can apply the preset like so:

```js
var myComp = app.project.activeItem;
var preCompLayer = myComp.selectedLayers[0];
// Path to your preset file below
var presetFile = File("/your-After-Effects-path/Presets/Image - Creative/Colorize - blue wash.ffx");

preCompLayer.applyPreset(presetFile);
```